# How to determine the class_weights for imbalanced dataset

Tags: keras, data-science, imbalanced-data

I am working on a dataset which imbalanced. I am trying to build the model with the help of `class_weights`. So on what basis can, I determine the `class_weights`.

The labels and its count are as below:

```
label    Count
2        47213
3        2096
4        2021
1        737
0        176
```

So what values should I give for the `class_weight` variable:

`model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32, class_weight=class_weight)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ `compute_class_weight` from `sklearn` for that.

```
from sklearn.utils import compute_class_weight
class_weights = compute_class_weight("balanced", np.unique(Y_train), Y_train)
```